# Access select statement result in plpgsql function

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I access the results of a select statement inside a plpgsql function to check its content?

I need to check whether the `ilike` function I have used returns any matched actors in my `people` table. If there are no matches I need to return 'No matching name' in the table 'actor_details' but if there is more than one distinct value I need to return something like 'Non-distinct actor name'.

If either of these conditions are true I need to break out of the function and simply return those text strings in the 'actor_details' table.

In my actual function I need to append several lines of text after this statement, hence the `RETURNS table`.

Any pointers would be great. Expected output defined in final two lines of code.

```
CREATE TABLE people (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name text NOT NULL,
    year_born integer,
    year_died integer
);

insert into people (id, name, year_born, year_died) values
(20000007,  'Humphrey Bogart',  1899,   1957)
(20000008,  'Marlon Brando',    1924,   2004)
(20000009,  'Richard Burton',   1925,   1984)
(200000010, 'Richard Hunt',     1985,   NULL)

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION actor_details(_pattern text) 
RETURNS table (actor_details text) 
AS $$

BEGIN
  select distinct concat(people.name, ' (', people.year_born, '-', people.year_died, ')') 
    into actor_details
  from people
  where people.name ilike('%' || _pattern || '%');
  
  --- THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
  IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0) then
    select 'No matching name' into actor_details;
  ELSIF (@@ROWCOUNT > 1) then
    select 'Non-distinct actor name';
  END IF; 
  return;              


END
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select * from actor_details('xxyyzz'); ---<<< Should return 'No matching name' in a column titled actor_details
select * from actor_details('Richarch'); ---<<< Should return 'Non-distinct actor name' in a column titled actor_details
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest aggregation in the query to get the `actor_details`:

```
select (case when count(*) = 0
             then 'No matching name'
             when count(distinct concat(p.name, ' (', p.year_born, '-', p.year_died, ')')) > 1
             then 'Non-distinct actor name'
             else max(concat(p.name, ' (', p.year_born, '-', p.year_died, ')'))
        end)
into actor_details
from people p
where p.name ilike('%' || _pattern || '%');
```

Then you don't need any additional logic after the query.

Comment: I get the error message 'syntax error at or near "then"' either when I i) replace an actor's name for the _pattern variable and run the query by itself or ii) use suggestion in the function itself. How might I fix that?

Comment: @dominiquealpinski . . . It was just a missing closing paren on the `when` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using `UNION ALL` and three queries selecting the string depending on the count of matches. You don't even need PL/pgSQL for that. (It seems odd that you want a set consisting of only one value. Simply returning a scalar would probably make more sense.)

```
CREATE
 OR REPLACE FUNCTION actor_details
                     (_pattern text) 
                     RETURNS table
                             (actor_details text) 
AS
$$
SELECT concat(people.name,
              ' (',
              people.year_born,
              '-',
              people.year_died,
              ')')
       FROM people
       WHERE people.name ILIKE '%' || _pattern || '%'
             AND (SELECT count(*)
                         FROM people
                         WHERE people.name ILIKE '%' || _pattern || '%') = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'No matching name'
       WHERE (SELECT count(*)
                     FROM people
                     WHERE people.name ILIKE '%' || _pattern || '%') = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Non-distinct actor name'
       WHERE (SELECT count(*)
                     FROM people
                     WHERE people.name ILIKE '%' || _pattern || '%') > 1;
$$ 
LANGUAGE sql;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=7da08119d29cf67edc76f673e6b107ff)

Comment: Is it possible to keep the format that I have used in my example above? I ask because I need to append a list of movies each actor has been in to the table 'actor_details' after this operation is complete. Using the suggested answer yields a function that returns the list of movies in the table but not actor name (or birth/death year).

Comment: It appears question asked has a couple satisfactory answers.  You should accept one of them. If you now also need to obtain data from another table then you need to ask another question. **Hint** it will involve a Join.